# How do I use torient command in autocad for mac?

Tags: autocad, autocad-plugin

Is there a way to install express tools on a mac

Is there any other commands which does the same job as "torient" on a mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Express Tools are essentially a set of program files (predominantly AutoLISP files), many of which were written several years, if not decades, ago (long before AutoCAD for Mac ever existed). The `TORIENT` command, for example, is part of the `acettxt.lsp` file, written by Randy Kintzley and Tom Stoeckel in October of 1998.

As such, these commands are heavily reliant on functionality only supported by Windows versions of AutoCAD, and so each command would need to be ported to AutoCAD for Mac to remove all reliance on functionality such as ActiveX.

Furthermore, since the use of such files is governed by the Autodesk EULA, any modification and subsequent publication to these files for use with AutoCAD for Mac would be a violation of the license terms. As such, you'll need to wait until Autodesk decide to do this work themselves.